# A 2-D shape bounded by a simple curve: can I change the area of the shape indefinitely without changing the perimeter of its boundary curve?

Tags: geometry

Let us say that in two dimensions I have some shape bounded by a curve $P$ with area $A$. Intuitively, I can imagine how I could increase the perimeter of the shape bounded by $P$ without changing $A$: I "ruffle" $P$ so that locally it changes like this from initially being straight: [image: ruffled boundary]

If the ruffles are uniform, I would still have the same area as before (each "ruffle in" is paired with a "ruffle out", cancelling minute gains in area).

**Can I change the area of a shape without affecting its perimeter indefinitely?**

In the above situation, I can have an increase in perimeter that can result in an increase of area or a decrease in area. This allows me to combine the two in order to always achieve an increase in perimeter, with no change in area. I am unable to imagine something similar for area (where I am able to increase the area with an increase in perimeter, or *increase the area with a decrease in perimeter*). Thus, I suspect the answer is no.

Am I right?

Comment: Depends on the shape - think about how convexity/concavity affects this.

Comment: Think of it as a string. Now its length cannot be changed. You can do with area whatever you want

Comment: @Awesome I changed the question as I realized I forgot the "indefinitely" part! I can "blow out" the perimeter like a balloon, in order to get the maximum area that can be bounded by that perimeter -- but there is a maximum area bounded by a fixed perimeter, while there is no maximum perimeter bounding a fixed area. Correct?

Comment: @user89 You mean area bounded by function and x axis as in integration?

Comment: "but there is a maximum area bounded by a fixed perimeter, while there is no maximum perimeter bounding a fixed area. Correct?" [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)

Comment: @Rahul You should write up a (very brief) answer so that I can accept it and give you internet points.

Comment: @Rahul Never mind! I just saw your profile -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) $4\pi A\le L^2$ places an upper bound on the area $A$ in terms of perimeter $L$. Similar in higher dimensions: the extremal set for this inequality is a ball.

There is no reverse estimate in general (a set can have arbitrarily large perimeter with arbitrarily small area). Even among  convex sets, a "thin needle" is a counterexample. However, if we allow ourselves to bring a convex set into better shape by an affine transformation, the following *reverse isoperimetric inequality* is available:

> For every convex set $C$ there is an affine image of $E$ whose area and perimeter satisfy $12\sqrt{3}A\ge L^2$. (Equality is attained for triangles).

This result holds in all dimensions: the extremal set for the reverse isoperimetric inequality is a simplex. Due to [Keith Ball](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201205).